# Youtube doesn't work in any browser

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, youtube

Guys I have a weird issue . No matter what , Youtube doesn't open in my PC . I use the same internet in my iphone 8 and there is nothing wrong there . Here is what I have tried so far :

- Rebooting the system
- Clearing cache and cookies
- Using multiple browsers to test ( Edge - Chrome - Firefox )
- Tried multiple dns providers like 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1
- Tried with multiple VPNs

I don't have an antivirus and also the firewall is off within windows .
Here is an screenshot of what I'm getting :

[image]

Comment: I also get this on sub pages This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=kir might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_FAILED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts, delete the line that contains [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com), you need administrator privilege to do this, use Win+R>notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts>Ctrl+Shift+Enter to do this, after that save the file.

Then open elevated cmd, use the same method used in the first step to do this, just this time type cmd in the run menu.

Then paste these commands:

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /all
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
```

Maybe these will help.

Comment: you are a legend ! I removed the hosts file and entered the commands that you mentioned and it's working again ! thank you so much !